# Sequence does not increment unless I store value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-xe

In regular SQL, my sequence increments every time I call `.NEXTVAL`:

```
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL; -- 54
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; -- 55
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; -- 56
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; -- 57
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL; -- 57 (54+3, correct)
```

However, in dynamic SQL inside a PL/SQL block it doesn't increment:

```
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL; -- 57
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
END;
/
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL; -- 57
```

... unless I store the value into a variable:

```
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL; -- 57 (!)
DECLARE
    FOO INTEGER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO FOO;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO FOO;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO FOO;
END;
/
SELECT PDF_DATOS_TITULO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL; -- 60 (57+3, correct)
```

What's the explanation? Is it a documented behaviour of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?

*<sub>Before you ask, SQL needs to be dynamic because sequence name is variable.</sub>*

Comment: I wonder if `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` without `INTO` doesn't fetch the result set, so `SEQ.NEXTVAL` is never looked at and therefore not incremented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you omit into or bulk returning into clauses ,Oracle will only parse the sql but not issue any fetches from it. It's not explicitly stated in the documents that this will happen, but the documentation does specify that you should use INTO when you have 1 row coming back and bulk if you have the possibility of more than one row coming back.

e.g.:

```
SQL> create sequence testseq;

Sequence created.

SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever';

Session altered.

SQL> exec execute immediate 'select testseq.nextval from dual';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name context off';

Session altered.

SQL> exit
```

we see in the trace that Oracle didn't bother with the FETCH stage:

```
=====================
PARSING IN CURSOR #140341213531640 len=32 dep=1 uid=83 oct=3 lid=83 tim=1363260261727946 hv=956010684 ad='7ac66b58' sqlid='56jwk2hwgr45w'
select testseq.nextval from dual
END OF STMT
PARSE #140341213531640:c=4001,e=50473,p=0,cr=2,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=1,og=1,plh=112670795,tim=1363260261727944
EXEC #140341213531640:c=0,e=219,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=1,plh=112670795,tim=1363260261728249
STAT #140341213531640 id=1 cnt=0 pid=0 pos=1 obj=79530 op='SEQUENCE  TESTSEQ (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=181 us)'
STAT #140341213531640 id=2 cnt=0 pid=1 pos=1 obj=0 op='FAST DUAL  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=1 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)'
CLOSE #140341213531640:c=4001,e=24391,dep=1,type=3,tim=1363260261752736
EXEC #140341212444728:c=8002,e=75407,p=0,cr=2,cu=0,mis=0,r=1,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=1363260261752783

*** 2013-03-14 11:24:29.866
CLOSE #140341212444728:c=0,e=37,dep=0,type=0,tim=1363260269866098
=====================
```

vs:

```
SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever';

Session altered.

SQL> var a number
SQL> exec execute immediate 'select testseq.nextval from dual' into :a;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set events '10046 trace name context off';

Session altered.
```

and now:

```
PARSING IN CURSOR #139830768042232 len=32 dep=1 uid=83 oct=3 lid=83 tim=1363260428931803 hv=956010684 ad='7ac66b58' sqlid='56jwk2hwgr45w'
select testseq.nextval from dual
END OF STMT
PARSE #139830768042232:c=0,e=38,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=1,plh=112670795,tim=1363260428931802
EXEC #139830768042232:c=0,e=86,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=0,dep=1,og=1,plh=112670795,tim=1363260428931917
FETCH #139830768042232:c=0,e=22,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=1,dep=1,og=1,plh=112670795,tim=1363260428931980
STAT #139830768042232 id=1 cnt=1 pid=0 pos=1 obj=79530 op='SEQUENCE  TESTSEQ (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=39 us)'
STAT #139830768042232 id=2 cnt=1 pid=1 pos=1 obj=0 op='FAST DUAL  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=2 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)'
CLOSE #139830768042232:c=0,e=0,dep=1,type=3,tim=1363260428931980
EXEC #139830768045912:c=0,e=294,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=1,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=1363260428931980

*** 2013-03-14 11:27:13.138
CLOSE #139830768045912:c=0,e=45,dep=0,type=0,tim=1363260433138490
=====================
```

the FETCH is seen. I think ideally Oracle should throw an error in the case where the user issues a select without INTO / BULK INTO defined.

Comment: Great answer. It probably makes sense to avoid wasting resources fetching stuff you're going to discard but I've hit an edge case. *(Now I wonder what happens when function or procedure calls are involved but this answer includes enough information if I want to test it myself.)*